# Android - Error when using Admob in React native

Tags: react-native, admob

I integrated Admob in my React Native Application for Android. I am getting below error when I try to generate a release build (gradlew assembleRelease),

*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'E:\React Native\MyApp\node_modules\react-native-share\android\build.gradle' line: 53
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-share'.

> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED*